# How to disable/ prevent scroll on the body while scrolling a fixed element, but without hiding scroll bar of the body itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, css-position

Whenever I scroll on the sidebar (which is position fixed) it should disable the page from scrolling. It doesn't mean that the body should be overflow hidden or hide the scrollbar on the body or page itself. It should just prevent the whole body/ page from scrolling when place the cursor on the sidebar and try to scroll it. The sidebar on the other hand doesn't need to have a scrollbar or more content inside it.

I have a *codepen* with the layout made with `html` and `css/sass`. But I'm not sure if this problem can be solved with pure css or if javascript is needed.

Comment: Codepen link: https://codepen.io/mathias95/pen/YzPYxLZ

Comment: Does this help? https://codepen.io/mathias95/pen/YzPYxLZ

Comment: @Alonas It seems like it's the same as before. Did you change anything?

Comment: @IjazAli I am already using touch-action: pan-y on the sidebar, but it still scroll the whole body when i'm scrolling/ have the cursor on the left sidebar

Comment: Sorry, I didn't do fork - this is the change I thought about https://codepen.io/alonabas/pen/QWwZByq

Comment: @Alonas What a cool solution, and made with pure css. Think i'm gonna go with that way thanks :) 

One thing that I had in mind. If I want the same behavior as you have created, but with the scroll bar starting at the top of the viewport and not only inside the "main-content" class area. How would I then create it. The markup is the exact same as you would find on YouTube's layout, which is what I am currently aiming for.

Comment: the idea is to make scroll on the element that is not parent of side bar. If you want it to start from the top you can wrap the top section and the main section in one div and make it scrollable, but side bar shouldn't be child of that div

Comment: @Alonas Thanks for the explanation :) I will take a look at it, and try to recreate it. Might reach back to you if I have any problems

Comment: you can do some small trick to avoid changing div parents and achieve this: https://codepen.io/alonabas/pen/BayqvLP